# WordPress Download Manager plugin

Tags: wordpress

I need WordPress Download Manager plugin that can be grouped into several categories, which are similar to the page http://www.auracms.org/download.html.

is there a wordpress plugin similar to that page?

please suggest me and thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I think "wordpress download manager" plugin will solve your problem. Please check the demos: 
https://demo.wpdownloadmanager.com/wpdmpro/category-blocks/
https://demo.wpdownloadmanager.com/wpdmpro/categories/